# AmCharts - Change chart font size dynamically?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I've noticed that the chart object has a `fontSize` property, but just changing it does nothing, even with `invalidateSize()` or `validateNow()`;

I need it to be dynamically as I don't have access to the chart's creation code.

This is for **AmCharts 3**

Code I've tried (does nothing) :

```
const chart = AmCharts.charts[0];
chart.fontSize = 25;
chart.validateNow();
chart.invalidateSize()
```

Comment: That code [works for me](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/7f12e17caee979e74a11ce731d7d8d76?editors=1010). Post a demo that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @xorspark you're right! it works, I must've screwed something. Want to post it as answer?

Comment: it wouldn't be appropriate for me to post an answer since it was an issue on your end and the code you posted was correct anyway. Might be worth posting what you did to fix your issue or delete the question. Up to you.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 10;